# Notations that are mnemonic outside of English

Tags: notation, big-list

Some conventional math notations seem arbitrary to English speakers but were mnemonic to non-English speakers who started them. To give a simple example, Z is the symbol for integers because of the German word *Zahl(en)* 'number(s)'. What are some more examples?

Comment: Common in Physics . . .

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a relevant example, but this TED talk explains (more or less accurately, apparently) why $x$ prevailed for the unknown in equations http://www.ted.com/talks/terry_moore_why_is_x_the_unknown.html

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I guess the use of the notation $Z(G)$ for the center of the group $G$ is because "center" in German is *Zentrum*.

Comment: @MJD that claim is made in a footnote (typeset humorously in fraktur) in paolo aluffi's algebra book

Comment: Why does $p$ stand for momentum?

Comment: Why does $m$ stand for slope?

Comment: a latin scholar will explain better, but the $p$ is from "impetus", a modified "petere"

Comment: @MJD : https://www.math.duke.edu//education/webfeats/Slope/Slopederiv.html

Comment: Astounding.  Thanks! (It says «I was told by [Mary Dolciani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_P._Dolciani) herself, that the SMSG group "decided" to use y=mx+b because of the French (Descartes, I presume)-"montant"»)

Comment: @exitingcorpse John Derbyshire in his _[Unknown Quantity](http://www.johnderbyshire.com/Books/Unknown/page.html)_ has a much more plausible explanation for _x_, quoting from Art Johnson’s _Classic Math_: Descartes invented the convention of using letter from the beginning of the alphabet to represent _data_ and letters from the end for _quaesita_. The printer asked him if the specific letter-choice mattered. Descartes said no. The printer chose _x_, since French uses the letters _y_ and _z_ heavily so he did not have as many spare punches for them.

Comment: That is a lovely-sounding theory, except that x is much more common in French than either y or z.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In topology the letter $F$ is commonly used to denote a closed set, from French [*fermé*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferm%C3%A9_%28topologie%29) 'closed [set]'. The common use of $K$ to denote a compact set is probably from German *kompakt*, as in [*kompakte Menge*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompakte_Menge) 'compact set' and [*kompakter Raum*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompakter_Raum) 'compact space'. The common use of $k$ to denote an arbitrary field is probably from German [*Körper*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_%28Algebra%29) 'field'. The common use of $G$ for an open set is probably from German *Gebiet* 'region', though as a mathematical term it [now means](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebiet_%28Mathematik%29) 'non-empty, connected, open set'. The notation $G_\delta$-*set* for the intersection of countably many open sets combines this $G$ with $\delta$ for German [*Durchschnitt*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnittmenge#Durchschnitt_.28Schnittmenge.2C_Schnitt.29) 'intersection'. Presumably $F_\sigma$-*set* for the union of countably many closed sets is from the $F$ above and $\sigma$ for French *somme* 'sum'. The $T$ in the names of the separation axioms $T_1,T_2$, etc. is from German [*Trennungsaxiom*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trennungsaxiom) 'separation axiom'.

Comment: And in algebra $K$ is often used to denote a field from the German _körper_ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Stefan: I believe that you're right; I'll add that.

Comment: And $G$ as in $G_\delta$ sets is probably from the German "Gebiet" (domain). I've also heard the $\delta$ being short for "Durchsnitt". I've always found it funny that $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ are from French and German respectively.

Comment: Could $G$ be for *geöffnet*?

Comment: @MTurgeon: Very unlikely: one speaks of *eine offene Menge*, not *eine geöffnete Menge*.

Comment: As you said F comes from the French word *fermé* to denote a closed set  but also O comes from the French word *ouvert* to denote an open set and this is not remarkable since the English word   starts with the same letter.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I suspect that most English speakers who use $O$ for an open set do so on account of *open* and aren't even aware of *ouvert*. (I prefer not to use $O$ at all, for anything, owing to its resemblance to $0$.)

Comment: The use of $U$ for open sets probably comes from the German _Umgebung_ "neighbourhood".

Answer (score 23):

Eigen (as in the eigen vectors of a matrix) is Dutch/German for "own".

Comment: + for mentioning Dutch ;)

Answer (score 12):

$\ln()$ for "logarithmus naturalis"?

My advisor also told me that the "socle of a ring" makes a little more sense when you know that "socle" is an architecture term for the support underneath a column or pedastal, and so the socle of a ring acts as a kind of "support for the ring." In some languages, the word for "pedestal" is something like "socle," so the meaning is less hidden there.

### Added

When I put "socle" into google translate, it autodetects it as "plinth" which is a relatively better-known word in English. It turns into "zócalo" in Spanish, sòcol in Catalan, Sockel in German, zoccolo in Italian, cokół in Polish, soco in Romanian, and 虹晶 in Mandarin.

Comment: I always wondered what socle was supposed to mean!

Comment: Not quite true: [*socle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socle) has that meaning in architecture, but the Latin base is actually *socculus*, a diminutive of *soccus* 'a slipper, a sock'.

Comment: the Dutch "sokkel" means pedestal

Comment: I made changes to pacify those with a deep knowledge of Latin roots. Apparently Latin roots are completely useless for understanding words if you go back far enough.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that. May be because the Finnish word "sokkeli" (obviously with the same root as the Dutch "sokkel" mentioned by ratcher freak) borrowed from a germanic language) meant something like plinth/die/footing/parapet (=the part of a house in contact with the ground). I just assumed that's what socle means in English as well :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah it *does* mean that in English, but English speakers hardly ever use it unless they know about architecture.

Answer (score 12):

A function is often called càdlàg if it is right-continuous and admits left limits. This term is from the french *continue à droite, limite à gauche*.

Comment: See also càglàd (obvious) and càllàl (*continue à l'une, limite à l'autre*, meaning continuous on one side, limit on the other side, and which side is continuous can depend on the point).

Answer (score 12):

The Klein $V$-group is  the four-element group with generators $a$ and $b$ and $a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = 1$.  The $V$ is for *vierergruppe* = "four-group".

Answer (score 9):

The reason the "Klein bottle" is called a bottle has its origin in something of a German pun on Fläche/Flasche; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)

Comment: this is also why when one wants to talk about two surfaces, one uses $S$ and $F$

Comment: Similarly, the Witch of Agnesi takes its English name from a pun in Italian, at least according to Wikipedia.

Comment: These answers should be posted as a separate answers to give them proper visibility.  Not everybody is aware of these facts.

Comment: Well, I thought about it, but it isn't really a piece of notation or a mnemonic as such, more an interesting tidbit (although I don't want to imply disapproval of your choice to post yours as an answer).

Comment: To a German speaker, Fläche and Flasche are quite different words. According to your link, it may be that 'Fläche' was mistranslated into English (by an English speaker) as 'bottle', and then back-translated into German as 'Flasche' -- which is undeniably a snappier name for it.

Comment: @TonyK, you are right, I should have called it an *English* pun (on a pair of German words).

Answer (score 8):

Łukasiewicz notation for logic represents $\land \lor \leftrightarrow$ with the letters $K A E$ respectively, so that for example $r\lor(p\land q)$ is $ArKpq$.  $K A E$ are the initials of the Polish words *koniunkcja*, *alternatywa*, *ekwiwalencja*.

I don't know why Łukasiewicz used $C$ to represent material implication.

Comment: $p \implies q$ ------ $p$ czyli $q$

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason? I am not a Polish speaker, but the examples I have found of *czyli* do not seem very much like material implication.

Comment: It's synonymous with 'therefore' and definitely can be used in this  context. Whether this was his reason for $C$ I can't say, but it certainly is a (perhaps somewhat archaic) way of expressing implication.

Comment: I am a Polish speaker, and it certainly seems reasonable. Here's a link to the relevant Wiktionary article: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/czyli

Comment: I had read that when I posted my comment above. I also consulted with Maciej Cegłowski, who though not a linguist is a native Polish speaker, and who agreed with me that it seems unlikely. My own suspicion is that $C$ is short for "conditional".

Answer (score 8):

Gabriel introduced the notation $\text{Sex}(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)$ to denote the category of left exact functors from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$. This because the Latin word for *left* (which is *sinister*) starts with an S.

Comment: Is the category of right exact functors called $\text{Dex}(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)$ from *dexter*?

Answer (score 7):

In homology one has a sequence of "differentials". Their images are usually denoted $B(X)$, apparently from the german word for "images", and their kernels $Z(X)$ from the german word for "cycles".

Comment: I always thought $B$ stood for "boundary".

Comment: @ZhenLin i think that's more of an ad-hoc thing that we do when working in english, to try to make more sense of it. one could then say we use $Z$ to stand for "zeroes", which is actually kind of pleasant

Answer (score 6):

The etymology of the $\sin$ function has a colorful history - it comes from *sinus*, the latin word for... well, bosom.  This was due to a mistranslation from Arabic text in the 12th century:  The word *jaib* means bosom, and since Arabic is written without short vowels, it was written essentially as *jb*.  But *jb* was also the spelling of *jiba*, which was a transliteration of the Sanskrit word for chord (the mathematical chord, ie a line passing through a circle, half the length of which is the sine of the angle from the center of the cicle).

Comment: According to my Latin dictionary, *sinus* also means "curve". Which might be a simpler explanation than the mistranslation one.

Comment: @detly but much less funny

Comment: All those meanings are present in Spanish: "[seno](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=seno) = concavity, bosom, and trig $\sin$"

Comment: And I doubt it's a mistranslation, the relation of meanings ("curved things") is apparent. See also this figure: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-DniqyzYnS0Y/Tf5Xx7mpoLI/AAAAAAAAANo/DOZbOj3WxMw/s1600/math.jpg

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this.  I'd be interested to see if there's more reasoning behind scholars believing that this was a mistranslation, but I don't have access to the sources in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Etymology

Comment: It could still be a mistranslation even if they meant sinus = curve.

Answer (score 5):

The logical-or symbol $\lor$ is a stylized letter ‘V’, the first letter of the Latin word *vel*.

(The $\land$ symbol arose later, derived by analogy from $\lor$.)

Comment: I always remember "and" because it looks like an "A". And "or" because it's an upside-down "and".

Answer (score 5):

QED comes from the latin *quod erat demonstrandum*

Comment: In french, it's CQFD for "ce qu'il faut démontrer" == "Which had to be demonstrated". Just for your curiosity.

Comment: @Fabinout Being french, I know that, although I'd say "Ce qu'il fallait démontrer". ;)

Answer (score 4):

The identity element of a group is $e$ for *einheit*, the German word for "identity".

Comment: I wondered about this just yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

In old Polish textbooks for secondary school complex numbers were denoted $\bf Z$, as *zespolone* and integers — $\bf C$, as *całkowite*.

Comment: Heresy ^^ ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The center of a group $G$ is denoted $Z(G)$.  The $Z$ is for “Zentrum”, which is the German word for ‘center’.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the good examples have been mentioned already.

- $+$ probably comes from Latin *et*, "and"
- $\tau$ is sometimes used for the golden ratio, from Greek *tomos*, "section" (same root as *atom*).
- $\sinh$ from Latin *sinus hyperbolus* (and so on)
- $\in$ from Latin *est*.
- $M$ for an arbitrary set from German *Menge*, crowd.
- $\mathrm E[x]$ for expectation is from German *Erwartung* or French *éspérance*.
- $\aleph$ (the cardinality of the countable numbers) is maybe from Hebrew *einsof*, infinity, or maybe just because it's the first letter of the Hebrew abjad.
- $m$ for slope may be from Latin *modulus*, "quantity", or French *monter*, "to climb".
- $e$ may be from German *Einheit*, "unity", because $\ln e = 1$.
- $c$ for the speed of light from Latin *celeritas*, "swiftness".

If you want to be pedantic, you could point out that there are a large number of mnemonics from other languages which also happen to work in English. For example

- $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ from German *Quotient*, *Reel*
- $\pi$ from Greek *perimitron* or from Latin *peripheriam*
- $I$ from French *intensite de courant*
- $\%$ comes from Italian *per cento*, "per hundred"
- $x$ is used for variables because it's uncommon in French

You might also count all symbols for the SI prefixes (atto-, yotta-, etc.) except the ones which have become productive in English (micro-, mega-, etc.) But that would be far too pedantic, even for me

Comment: As long as we're here, we might as well include the [actual reason](https://www.ted.com/talks/terry_moore_why_is_x_the_unknown?language=en) that $x$ is used for variables.

Answer (score 1):

In Polya's enumeration theorem the letter $Z(G)$ which is used for the cycle index of the permutation group $G$ originates with the German word *Zyklenzeiger*, I think.